# If a fair die (with 6 faces) is cast twice, what is the probability that the two numbers obtained differ by 2?

Tags: probability

Don't think that this is my homework. Also, I do not have my graduation in mathematics. I was looking at different exams and their sample papers and came across this question...

### If a fair die (with 6 faces) is cast twice, what is the probability that the two numbers obtained differ by 2?

> (A) 1/12
>
> (B) 1/6
>
> (C) 2/9
>
> (D) 1/2

I believe the answer is 2/9 and I want to find out if I am correct.

For the first time rolling the dice, probability would be 1/6

(as per my knowledge)  there are 8 possible combinations for rolling the dice for the second time and difference between two numbers is equal to 2

```
1 -> 3

2 -> 4


   |-> 1
3 -|
   |-> 5

   |-> 2
4 -|
   |-> 6

5 -> 3

6 -> 4
```

And thus, final probability as per my knowledge should be (1/6)(8/6) = 2/9

Am I correct?

Also I would welcome better approaches that can solve this problem more quicker.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  However, a probability cannot exceed $1$, so it does not make sense to write $(1/6)(8/6) = 2/9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total number of possible outcomes$=6*6=36$
P(The outcomes differ by 2)$=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(6,4),(5,3),(4,2),(3,1)\}$
$$P=\dfrac{8}{36}=\dfrac{2}{9}$$
So, yes you are correct!

Answer (score 5):

Mark one of the dice and let $D$ denote the event that it results in one of $\{1,2,5,6\}$.

If $E$ denotes the event that the two results differ by $2$ then:$$P(E)=P\left(D\right)P\left(E\mid D\right)+P\left(D^{\complement}\right)P\left(E\mid D^{\complement}\right)=\frac46\frac16+\frac26\frac26=\frac8{36}=\frac29$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} + & 1&2&3&4&5&6 \\ \hline 
1&&&*&&& \\
2&&&&*&& \\
3&*&&&&*& \\
4&&*&&&&* \\
5&&&*&&& \\
6&&&&*&&
\end{array}$$

From the above sample space, we can see that the probability that two numbers differ by 2 is $P = \frac{8}{36} = \frac{2}{9}$.

Using this method, we can easily generalize it to an N-sided die. If we roll the die twice, the probability that two numbers differ by M is $P = \frac{2(N-M)}{N^2}$.

When N is 6 and M is 2 (as in this case), P becomes $\frac{2}{9}$.